# load latex table to r markdown

Tags: r, markdown

I have some latex tables that I generated via stata.

I am trying to incorporate them onto r markdown so that I can create a comprehensive pdf with all the figures (some generated in r markdown, some in the form of latex).

I have a many tex files like this and would like to know how I can load the latex codes to R markdown.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[margin=.25in]{geometry}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htbp]\centering
    \def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
    \caption{Share Ownership for 1927 (Third Degree Connections, No Weights)}
    \begin{tabular}{l*{5}{c}}
    \hline\hline
                &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)}         \\
    \hline
    No. of Firms&      -0.002         &      -0.011         &      -0.015         &      -0.011         &      -0.015         \\
                &     (0.018)         &     (0.025)         &     (0.026)         &     (0.025)         &     (0.026)         \\
                &    [-0.000]         &    [-0.000]         &    [-0.000]         &    [-0.000]         &    [-0.000]         \\
    Poors Dummy &       0.653\sym{***}&       0.668\sym{***}&       0.641\sym{***}&       0.657\sym{***}&       0.632\sym{***}\\
                &     (0.166)         &     (0.167)         &     (0.167)         &     (0.167)         &     (0.167)         \\
                &     [0.002]\sym{***}&     [0.002]\sym{***}&     [0.002]\sym{***}&     [0.002]\sym{***}&     [0.002]\sym{***}\\
\hline\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is R markdown?

Comment: Here you can find the answer: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/raw-latex.html. In essence, put the tex code in a ```{=latex} chunk.